# Testar conexao com a internet de uma aplicação

Tags: android

Tenho um app que conecta com a *webservice* mas o problema é que quando estou com o 3G, ele dá erro.
Quando a conexão esta boa, com uma wi-fi por exemplo funciona perfeitamente.

Tenho alguns algoritmos que testam a conexão, mas todos valida somente se esta conectado, e as vezes o 3G tem rede mas não conecta com a internet, gerando erro no app.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a verificar a internet antes do app tentar consumir a *webservice*?

Comment: Opa, espero que te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111898/identificar-o-tipo-de-conex%C3%A3o-3g-4g-e-ou-wifi

Answer (score 9):

Esse método faz a validação se existe conexão.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
 }
```

Durante o consumo ao web service, vc pode adicionar um try catch e pegar a execption UnknownHostException e tratá-la.

```
  try {
    //seu código
  } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
   // trata o erro de conexão.
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, não se esqueça da permissão no Manifest. Se não, sua aplicação não conseguirá conectar.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Depois, crie um método em algum local de sua preferência e onde faça sentido na sua aplicação.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
       manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Um "if" básico te devolve o status da conexão.

```
if(isOnline()) { 
    //faz algo :)
}
```