# Identificar o tipo de conexão 3g, 4g e/ou Wifi

Tags: android-studio

Bom dia!

Estou precisando checar o tipo de conexão que o aparelho esta por exemplo 2g, 3g, 4g ou Wifi.

Pois após checar o tipo de conexão preciso limitar o aparelho a realizar algumas ações.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, agradeço.

Att.

Comment: Esses links odem ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g

Comment: Obrigado Diego Felipe esta sendo muito útil os links. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro adicione essa tag ao manifest do projeto para permitir acesso ao status da conexão

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Depois crie essa função aonde for mais conveniente:

```
public static String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);      
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(info==null || !info.isConnected())
        return "-"; //sem conexão
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        return "WIFI";
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        int networkType = info.getSubtype();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: //api<8 : troque por 11
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: //api<9 : troque por 14
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:  //api<11 : troque por 12
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:  //api<13 : troque por 15
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:    //api<11 : troque por 13
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "?";
         }
    }
    return "?";
}
```

Isso basicamente atende a necessidade de sua pergunta pois com o resultado do return você pode decidir o que fazer em diante, recomendo consultar os links do comentário do Diego para informações avançadas