# Como bloquear meu app se nao tiver internet

Tags: java, android

Tou criando um aplicativo que precisa de internet,
 Caso o celular desta pessoa fique sem internet o aplicativo nao iria ser iniciado pois só abriria se estivesse com internet.
Como fazer isso alguém ajuda ?

Comment: Você sabe ver se o celular tem acesso à internet?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que está mais pra relacionado. O foco principal é o bloqueio quando não há conexão. Pra isso eu coloquei na resposta a verificação e sei indiquei o método finish para sair da aplicação. =D

Comment: @acklay entendo, pode até ser, mas é que as vezes é tão pequeno o detalhe que bastaria seguir a lógica e decidir por si o que fará dentro do if, tem muita pergunta assim, que muda detalhes pequenos, geralmente acabam como dup. Mas vamos ver o que o pessoal da fila de analise pensa :) ... De qualquer forma eu votei na sua resposta pelo excelente suporte e pelo exemplo no Kotlin :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu também acho que é duplicata, mas não quis usar o "martelo" antes do AP responder ao meu comentário

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você tem toda razão, era um detalhe simples. Eu na verdade só ia colocar a  condição para finalizar a aplicação, e aí indicar a questão no qual constaria o método para consulta da conexão. Mas aí decidi inserir aqui mesmo. =]

Comment: @acklay costumo responder perguntas que logo em seguida voto pra fechar, mesmo pela questão do rapido suporte, eu não sou contra suporte, desde que não fuja do fundamento ideal da comunidade, que eu pessoalmente acredito ser a organização do conteudo, no caso detalhar para a necessidade especifica como você fez foi o ideal realmente e se você mesmo puder votar para fechar melhor ainda (dependendo do caso da pergunta), exemplos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3635+is%3Aclosed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples é deixar o usuário entrar na aplicação e dentro você verificar se existe a conexão. Caso não haja conexão com a internet, usar o método `finish()` para finalizar a aplicação. Veja:

```
if(!isOnline()){
   finish();
}
```

Um [método simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29381/35406) para verificar é usando o [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
         getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Aqui tem uma pergunta sobre [teste de conexão com internet eficaz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197035/teste-de-conex%C3%A3o-com-internet-eficaz) que talvez a [resposta do Ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197087/35406) possa esclarecer mais algum detalhe.

---

No **[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/)** ficaria assim:

```
fun isOnline(): Boolean {
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
}
```

Para usar esta função no Kotlin, segue a mesma lógica do JAVA.

Comment: Perfeito! Aqui está o link para a documentação se quiser incluir na sua resposta: [getActiveNetworkInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)